# Pre-amplifier to drive LM324 Op-Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, microphone, gain, preamp

I want use Electret microphone [Pre-amplifier](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf) described in TI document, with Color light organ. Will the output level of this pre-amp enough to drive LM324 Op-Amps on [Color organ](https://s29.postimg.org/n78d1qe9j/Color_Organ_4ch.png)? Input signal goes to VR1 "Master level" potentiometer. Also, is the standard Line level output of consumer audio electronics enough for connecting it to VR1?

[image]

Comment: Rerun your simulation with a 1.6k resistor in parallel with your 100k resistor. 4 10k pots in parallel are the equivalent of 2.5 k. With these tied to the wiper of VR1 (5k) the worst case input load is 1.67k.

Comment: I want modify pre-amp for 12V, so I calculated R1 and C3 values based on [formulas](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu765/tidu765.pdf) (9) and (11) respectively, and got R1 = 21kΩ and C3 = 1.51uF. Is that correct? What will be the output voltage of the op-amp with 12V power supply?